# how create highlighting/illumination like voicebase

Tags: speech-to-text

Is possible reproduce online final transcript, something like this:
https://app.voicebase.com/autonotes/private_detail/17519536/hash=apuaYW1qaW6WaG7FlmaTcWuPmJ2YlWZsmGjHkZluxZhmlpaUl2ebmptrl5vE?vbt=0, illuminating each word or phrase

Answer (score 0):

The transcript was generated using Voicebase speech recognition software. One of the formats in which the transcript is provided by Voicebase is called SRT. This format has the start time and end time of the sentences. In this case, the webpage you pointed to is using the SRT and the player time of the audio to highlight the sentences.